# Defining Navigation Property of an Entity in Olingo

Tags: java, oop, odata, olingo

Basically I am trying to map an existing framework to Entity Concept in OData with Apache Olingo Library. I have searched like everywhere but I am unable to see how to define a Navigation Property of an Entity Type. Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Olingo V4 tutorial on how to create navigation between entities: http://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata4/tutorials/navigation/tutorial_navigation.html

The concept works for V2 as well. Just add the navigation to your EDMProvider classes and they should appear in the metadata document.